# Webpack compilation gives error on src attribute

Tags: laravel, webpack, vue.js, laravel-elixir

I'm using VueJS and in order to bind the src attribute, you do something similar to this:

`<img v-bind:src="image" :alt="alt" :style="styles" />`

or

`:src="image"`

However, whenever I run webpack and it compiles, I get this error:

> ERROR in
>   ./resources/assets/js/components/slider/templates/slideimage.html
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./image
>   in --file here--

But whenever I do a random attribute like `:class="image"` it works fine. So it's something with src that it doesn't like. This isn't a vue issue, but a webpack issue.. Other projects that don't use webpack work fine when they do it this way. How do I get webpack to ignore this and compile it regardless? I tried to setup my gulp using vueify, but it gave me the worst headache ever (since I'm using Laravel elixir, their gulp wrapper). Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-elixir-vueify to implement Vueify in elixir, it couldn't be easier!

Comment: Thank you! This worked wonders :) I have it working in my project now and am able to use :src="image"